# Can i break my hardware while manipulating on a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, system

Can I damage my hardware if I use bad practice while programming in a virtual machine?

If I manipulate memory incorrectly or change the kernel code, for example, can that damage my hardware?

Comment: You may assume that none action in **guest** system (which is running under VM) may broke **host** system (which runs VM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you poorly use hardware, you *could* damage your system, however, most machines have built in protection against this.

What you mentioned about changing kernal/OS code could damage the VM, but you'd have to try pretty hard to damage your normal OS doing that.

Comment: @Ms.Simpson, If the answer solved your problem, consider clicking the green check mark next to it.

Comment: @Ms.Simpson: If it addressed your question, you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/65088/173356)

Comment: @Seki Did a way better job at that, completely forgot there was a whole page on it.